Argument of type Buffer is not assignable in writeFile
I am trying to upload image in local file system using next.js 14 in a server action file.
But writeFile function from "fs/promises" is not taking Buffer as second argument.
Here is my code snippet for that function
'use server'

import path from "path";
import { writeFile } from "fs/promises";


async function uploadImage(file: File) {
    try {
        // upload file logic here
        const uploadedFileName = `${Date.now()}_${file.name}`;
        const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'public', 'images', uploadedFileName);

    const arrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
    const buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);
    await writeFile(filePath, buffer); // This line causing the issue 
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
}

}
await writeFile(filePath, buffer); 

This is causing compile time issue in my ide (VS code) saying that argument of type 'Buffer' is not assignable to type of 'string | ArrayBufferView | ...
How can I get this to work?
Note: I was using Typescript for the whole project and this is also a typescript file

running this  npm install --save-dev @types/node solved my issue. Anyone can add answer with more explanation so that I can approve

I cannot reproduce your issue. If @types/node were not available, then these 4 should err: 1. import path from "path"; 2. import { writeFile } from "fs/promises"; 3. process 4. Buffer. So it seems like somehow you previously had @types/node of a mismatched version. I tried npx create-next-app@14 something but there are no mismatched versions.

I can artificially create the issue if I Ctrl + click on Buffer, then go to line 285 of node_modules/@types/node/ts5.6/buffer.buffer.d.ts and delete extends Uint8Array; it will result in the Error message that you described. But that means modifying a file that should not be modified. Another way to artificially create the issue is by doing npm install --save-dev @types/node@15. I don't think the 2 ways I showed were the cause of your issues, though, as npm install --save-dev @types/node did not solve either.

Maybe you are right. But for my case npm install --save-dev @types/node made the error go away. Maybe there was some missing or mismatched versions or maybe vscode specific issue. Or maybe the "npm install" command would also solved the issue.
